# Binding Custom Object From Header Asp.Net Core WebApi

Tags: c#, attributes, model-binding, asp.net-core-webapi, request-headers

How do i bind an object from header. Am using the `[FromHeader(Name = "Custom-Object")]` but it seems to only be able to bind strings and sting arrays. Do i need to write custom binding or am i missing something here? I wonder why fromheader cannot bind complex object like frombody?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816200/fromheader-asp-net-core-binding-to-default-value

Answer (score 1):

Write custom binder by using [IModelBinder and IModelBinderProvider](https://www.asptricks.net/2019/04/custom-model-binding-through-header-in.html) that should resolve your problem.