# FromHeader Asp.NET Core binding to default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, http-headers, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm testing Asp.Net core WebApi with the following basic controller:

```
[Route("test")]
public class TestController
{
    [Route("mult")]
    [HttpGet]
    public int Multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

Then, in Fiddler, I send the following request:

[image]

And, for some reason, the response is 0. Both `x` and `y` are binded to the default integer value when entering the method.

I also tried:

```
[Route("test")]
public class TestController
{
    [Route("mult")]
    [HttpGet]
    public int Multiply([FromHeader]int x, [FromHeader]int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

But the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

form headers accept `string` not `int`  so your code should be

```
[Route("test")]
public class TestController
{
        [Route("mult")]
        [HttpGet]
        public int Multiply([FromHeader]string x, [FromHeader]string y)
        {

            return Int32.Parse(x) * Int32.Parse(y);
        }
}
```

you have to get values of `x` and `y` in `string` and convert it to `int`

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it was initially thought this wouldn't be needed and they were waiting for feedback.  However, it looks like it will likely be in the 2.1.0 milestone according to [issue 5859](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5859).

Comment: This is very nice to hear. Also, this is badly documented.